# Form.errors not rendering in TemplateView

Tags: python, django

Upon submitting a form, the desired outcome is to display validation error messages in the template if the form is not valid. When it comes to what I'm actually getting, no error messages are showing up in the template at all even though the form does in fact catch the errors.

I'm trying get the desired outcome using just TemplateView.

```
class TestUserRegisterPage(TestCase):
    '''Verify that a message is flashed when attempting to
    create a new account with a username already taken.'''

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        user = User.objects.create_user("Mock")
        cls.payload = {
            "username": "Mock",
            "password1": "secret",
            "password2": "secret"
        }

    def test_new_user_registeration_fail(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("users:register"),
            data=self.payload
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        print(response.content)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "users/register.html")
        self.assertContains(response, "A user with that username already exists")
```

- `AssertionError: False is not true : Couldn't find 'A user with that username already exists' in response`

```
-> form = self.get_context_data()['register_form'](payload)
(Pdb) n
> users\views.py(30)post()
-> if form.is_valid():
(Pdb) form.errors
{'username': ['A user with that username already exists.'], 'password2': ['This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.', 'This password is too common.']}
(Pdb)
```

```
class UserRegisterPage(TemplateView):

    template_name = "users/register.html"

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['register_form'] = NewUserForm
        return context

    def get(self, request):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        context['register_form'] = context['register_form']()
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request):
        payload = request.POST
        form = self.get_context_data()['register_form'](payload)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.add_message(
                request, messages.INFO,
                "Your account is registered...now you may login!"
            )
            return HTTPRedirectResponse(reverse("topics:listing"))
        context = self.get_context_data()
        context['register_form'] = form
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

```
{% block content %}
  <form action="{% url 'users:register' %}" method="POST">
  {% if form.errors %}
    <ul>
    {% for error in form.errors.values %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  {% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
  {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Those `self.assertXxx` functions are designed to abort the server in case of bad conditions.  They are not designed to validate form responses. If you want to validate fields and return errors, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: In the template you refer the form as `form` but in the view you have passed it as `register_form` in the context... Not to mention the form errors would not be rendered even the form itself would not be rendered (One should actually open the page and see rather than just running a test)